# Failure using method; 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: python, ansible

As [evidenced here](https://travis-ci.org/naftulikay/ansible-role-vagrant-go-dev/jobs/268494113#L712), I have noticed a strange new behavior in Ansible.

I have [an Ansible role named "degoss"](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss) which installs [Goss](https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss/) along with some test files to a system, executes the tests, and then removes all traces of them. I'm using [a callback plugin](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/blob/master/callback_plugins/goss_format.py) to format the output and [a custom module](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/blob/master/library/goss.py) to invoke Goss.

When tests fail, rather than getting sensible output, in newer versions of Ansible (around 2.3 as far as I can tell), I get the following unintuitive error message and no output whatsoever from my plugin:

```
[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_failed) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.default.CallbackModule object at 0x7fb5e92efd50>):
'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Now, when I search through [`ansible.plugins.callback.default.CallbackModule`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.2.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py), I don't see any invocations of `dumps`. When I search through [`ansible.plugins.callback.CallbackBase`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.2.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py), I do see three invocations of dumps. In my own callback plugin and custom module, I have `try`/`except` blocks wrapping all of my calls to `json.dumps`.

What's even worse is that I can't seem to replicate the issue consistently. I can't replicate it locally, and it only appears when a task has failed. My success/failure logic is below:

```
succeed(module, **result) if rc == 0 else fail(
    module, "Goss Tests Failed.", **result
)
```

My `succeed`/`fail` methods are defined as such:

```
def succeed(module, **kwargs):
    module.exit_json(changed=False, failed=False, goss_failed=False, **kwargs)

def fail(module, message, **kwargs):
    module.fail_json(msg=message, failed=True, goss_failed=True, **kwargs)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a guess:
ansible's [callback plugin loader](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/68aeaa58a89fdcf31511ddc61d7e4b51c0099d6a/lib/ansible/plugins/loader.py#L473) creates a module in `ansible.plugins.callback` which happens to also contain a [json module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/869a31849224a8fff88364ceea3db9b3e6b475d7/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py). When your callback plugin [imports json](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/blob/master/callback_plugins/goss_format.py#L9) you get `ansible.plugins.callback.json`, which doesn't contain `dumps`. You can fix this by adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` to your plugin.

The reason you can't reproduce it might be that you're using Python 3 locally, which defaults to absolute imports.

Comment: Excellent catch, I have updated my module, will try to reproduce the functionality now.

Comment: Confirmed: this was the issue. Adding the `absolute_import` fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, just want to point out that there are two files into which the import statement needs to be added.

> playbooks/callback_plugins/sqs.py

and

> playbooks/callback_plugins/task_timing.py

I had missed updating the task_timing.py file and so the error persisted. Pointing this out here, in case someone else also faces the same issue.

Source :[edx configuration repo - diff](https://github.com/edx/configuration/commit/94ff77d436afd52c48b0cb51bee999589c1ec3d9)